# Nginx "upstream" directive is not allowed here

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to set up a Django website with uwsgi and nginx. I created configuration file `mysite.conf`:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/path/to/mysite/mysite.sock;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    charset     utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 350M;

    # Django media and static files
    location /media  {
        alias /home/path/to/mysite/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/path/to/mysite/static;
    }

    # Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/path/to/mysite/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

And it gives this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:2
```

I don't why it happens. I followed this tutorial: https://tonyteaches.tech/django-nginx-uwsgi-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i included configuration files before http tag.
It should be:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if your file is being deployed over the directory `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` but the default config is including files from `http.d` instead:

```
include /etc/nginx/http.d/*.conf;
```

so try also to deploy it over `/etc/nginx/http.d/`